# Reading port register and print

Tags: arduino-micro, port-mapping, avr-gcc

I am playing with port registers directly to improve speed on a Arduino micro. I have no problem **writing** them, like

```
PORTF &= B11101111
```

However, when I try to **read** and print it, things get funny and I hope to know why.

Observation 0:

```
byte dat = PORTF;
Serial.print(dat,BIN);
```

produces a single 0, where I am expecting 8 0's as for a byte. And, even when I check that a digitalRead correctly gets a 1 from PF5 or A2,

Observation 1:

```
byte dat = PORTF;
Serial.print(dat,BIN);
Serial.print(dat,BIN);
```

produces a compiler error like

```
...cores\arduino\Print.cpp: In function 'println.constprop':
...cores\arduino\Print.cpp:143:1: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
}
^
```

Comment: To reproduce your compiler problem, please post a minimized sketch showing the error. And tell us which PC system (Win, Linux, Mac) you're using. [edit] your question, don't put additional information in a comment, please!

Comment: the compiler error is the error of the compiler. use Arduino boards package 1.6.21. this is not the right way to work with registers. and `PORTF &= B11101111` is `PORTF = PORTF & B11101111`. so if PORTF is all zeros, the result is zero

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/70104/adc-register-always-returning-high/70108#70108

Comment: The compiler error is a compiler bug. What version of the IDE are you using? If it's not the latest, you may want to upgrade.

Comment: @EdgarBonet, it is a problem of avr-gcc used in Arduino AVR core 1.6.22 and 1.6.23. the version in AVR core 1.8.0 and 1.8.1 has the problem of 'over-optimizing'. (1.8.0 was next after 1.6.23. 1.7.x was skipped).

Comment: @Juraj: What do you mean by “over-optimizing”? Another compiler bug?

Comment: @EdgarBonet, this one https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/70597/function-parameter-of-type-int-not-working-as-expected#comment153249_70597 and one more was on Arduino Forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `Serial.print()` and it's siblings cuts all leading zeros. So `0b00001111` get's displayed as `1111` and `0b00000000` as `0`. So you actually get what you expect. It's just printing different.

Also, when reading `PORTF`, you actually read the output state of the pins, as you have set it before. If you want to read the real input level of the pins, you should read `PINF` instead.

Though I don't know, where that segmentation fault came from.